# How to send a value to other page with condition in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

My `app.js` below:

```
var app = angular.module('dbpjkApps', ['ionic'])

app.controller('kategoriCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.listKat = [
        {kat: 'math'}, {kat: 'physics'}, {kat: 'English'}, {kat: 'bahasa'},
    ]})
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('menu1', {
            url: '/menu1',
            templateUrl: 'xxx.html' //this is condition what i mean. 
        })

        .state('login1', {
            url: '/login1',
            templateUrl: 'login1.html'
         });

         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login1');
    })
})
```

At the 1st step user are choosing category from `select/combobox` on `login1.html`.

How to write condition when user chooses math or physics, and then open page `menu1.html` or `menu2.html` accordingly?
And how to get value that user chooses from `login1.html` on `menu1.html` or `menu2.html`?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-model on combobox which will give you selected value

and just define the state in stateProvider

```
.state('menu1', {
            url: '/menu1',
            templateUrl: 'menu1.html' //this is condition what i mean. 
        })


.state('menu2', {
            url: '/menu2',
            templateUrl: 'menu2.html' //this is condition what i mean. 
        })
```

After that just check the ng-model value of combobox in Login Controller after that just add following line to redirect the page

```
if(condition1){
       $state.go('menu1'); 
}else if(condition2){
       $state.go('menu2'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First prepare your config

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('menu1', {
            url: '/menu1/:userChoice',
            templateUrl: 'xxx.html' //this is condition what i mean. 
        })

        .state('menu1', {
            url: '/menu2/:userChoice', //This is how to create params for the state
            templateUrl: 'xxx2.html' //this is an other state. 
        })

        .state('login1', {
            url: '/login1',
            templateUrl: 'login1.html'
         });

         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login1');
    })
```

To check where to go in your controller you can have:

```
    app.controller('kategoriCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.listKat = [
        {
            kat: 'math'
        }, {
            kat: 'physics'
        }, {
            kat: 'English'
        }, {
            kat: 'bahasa'
        },
    ]

    //Having defined the ng-model in the select tag in your html tempalte.

    $scope.choice = $scope.listKat[0];

    $scope.changeState = function () {
        if ($scope.choice == "math") {
            $state.go("menu1", {
                userChoice: $scope.choice
            });
        } else if ($scope.choice == "physics") {
            $state.go("menu2", {
                userChoice: $scope.choice
            });
        }

    }
})
```

Then in your math1Ctrl to take the params:

```
app.controller('math1Ctrl', function($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams.userChoice); // math or physics
})
```

Comment: Thank You for your respons but, I use <button class="button button-full button" ui-sref="menu1">OK</button> on Login1.html is it true?

Comment: You should better remove ui-sref. In case you need to define which state to move to based on which value user has chosen you should better use a function like `$scope.changeState`. To summarize `<button class="button button-full button" ng-click="changeState()">OK</button>`

Comment: would you share more details please..? :)